# Spring + Flex + BlazeDs configuration

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

How Flex knows to call the particular service in Spring framework.

I give in Flex side:

```
<mx:remoteObject id="myObj" destination="mySpringservice"/>
```

And remote-config.xml file:

```
<destination id="mySpringservice">
    <properties>
        <factory>spring</factory>
        <source>mySpring</source>
    </properties>
</destination>
```

And how server knows to the particular flex remote object calls to particular spring service. any thing need to configure in service-config.xml file?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I' don't know about your config but if you use [Spring BlazeDS Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) you don't need to configure destinations in the remote-config. Instead of that you can make a spring bean to be a destination in the spring config file like this

```
<bean id="myService" class="package.MyService">
    ...
    <flex:remoting-destination />
</bean>
```

Comment: This is correct.  Check out my Refcard to see all the steps for setting up the Spring BlazeDS Integration: http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/flex-spring-integration

Comment: Indeed, no more ambiguity about what is put where. Plus, you can fully benefit of some of the great Spring features, such as security. Make sure to check this article out, if you need further convincing: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/spring_blazeds_integration.html